# Limit Points of a Sequence in the Excluded Point Topology

Tags: general-topology

> Consider $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the excluded point topology $\tau_0 = \{U \subseteq \mathbb{R} : 0 \notin U \text{ or } U = \mathbb{R}\}$. Identify the limit points of the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_0)$.

So, I've gotten quite far with this, I think I have shown that $0$ is a limit point of this sequence. For points $x\neq 0$ I am struggling to reach a conclusion, this is what I have:

Consider $x \neq 0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let the elements of $\{U \subseteq \mathbb{R} : 0 \notin \mathbb{R}\}$ be denoted by $U_i$ for $i\in I$ where $I$ is some index set, and note that these are all open sets. The open sets which contain $x$ are $\{x\}, \mathbb{R},$ and $U_i, \forall i \in I$. Note that $\{x\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $\{x\} \subseteq U_i$. Thus, $x$ is a limit point for the sequence if there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(1+\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \{x\}$, $\forall n \geq N$.

So, would it be correct to conclude that the limit points of this sequence are $\{0, 1+\frac{1}{n}\}$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions are not quite right. The correct definition is the following:

> $x$ is a limit point of a sequence $a_n$ if for all open sets $U$ that contain $x$ and all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an index $m>n$ such that $a_m \in U$.

First, let's prove that $0$ is a limit point: the only open set that contains $0$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself, and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a $m>n$ (take $m=n+1$ for example) such that $a_m \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now take an $x \neq 0$. The set $\{x\}$ is open in $\tau_0$. If $x$ is a limit point we must have $a_n = x$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ which cannot happen since the terms of $a_n$ are distinct. Hence the set of limit points of $a_n$ is $\{0\}$.